# AlethZero and Mix problems

Tags: dapps, mix, alethzero

I am trying to get started and learn Ethereum development, mainly using the tutorial at [dappsforbeginners.wordpress.com](https://dappsforbeginners.wordpress.com/tutorials/your-first-dapp/). However, several features referred to in the tutorial are simply not appearing in my client, or the client has been changed since the article was written. My client has no "pending" panel or a "contract" panel.

In addition to this, my Mix client crashes upon opening. I understand these aren't stable releases yet, so should I give up using these tools for now? If so, what tools can I use to start getting hands on experience? I am uncomfortable with CLI but I will do if I need to. Any good suggestions on how to get started?

EDIT: I am using Windows 10 and Mist Version 1.01. Now I see that when I run the executable, the first message displayed in the terminal window that appears is `Qt: Untested Windows version 10.0 detected!`. This must be what's causing the intermittent crashing.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to hear that you're having problems.

I'm not sure who put that tutorial together, but perhaps you could contract them about the disparities?    Check out the official docs at http://ethdocs.org.   We would love your feedback on whether or not you find them useful, any typos or other problems you see with them, at http://github.com/ethereum/homestead-guide.

For the Mix crash, you don't mention your OS, or Mix version.   Please could you look through https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/issues and see if anything looks like your issue?   We have something very similar listed for OS X Yosemite.

I would like to suggest that you join the http://www.ethchamps.org/ Slack instance.  That is a new community where people who are enthusiastic about Ethereum and want to help each other is starting up.    I'm sure you will find many fellow-travelers there who will have good suggestions on how to get going.

Best wishes!